# How does a generator function work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I read these line of codes from an article and they showed the work flow of function generator.

```
var foo, f;

foo = function* () {
  console.log('generator 1');
  console.log('yield 1', yield 'A');
  console.log('generator 2');
  console.log('yield 2', yield 'B');
  console.log('generator 3');
};

f = foo();

console.log('tick 1');
console.log(f.next('a'));
console.log('tick 2');
console.log(f.next('b'));
console.log('tick 3');
console.log(f.next('c'));
console.log('tick 4');
console.log(f.next('d'));
```

This is the log in the terminal:

```
tick 1
generator 1
{ value: 'A', done: false }
tick 2
yield 1 b
generator 2
{ value: 'B', done: false }
tick 3
yield 2 c
generator 3
{ value: undefined, done: true }
tick 4
{ value: undefined, done: true }
```

But I can not find the way to easily understand this flow, it is kind of weird. If someone has a simple approach to this problem, please help to explain.

Comment: What do you find weird in particular?

Comment: The order is perfectly correct and very clear after you learn about how your code forms an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Basics

Calling the generator function returns an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator).

Calling `.next()` on an iterator returns an object in the form:

```
{ 
  value // current value of the iterator, 
  done  // boolean indicating if iteration is finished 
}
```

Calling `.next()` on the iterator provided by the generator, runs the code from **the current paused point in the generator to the next `yield`**, pauses the generator on this next `yield` and pushes out whatever is the `yield` value as the value returned from the `.next()` method of the iterator, in the object form shown above.

Anything that you pass into `.next()` of this iterator will be returned from the currently paused `yield` within the generator.

Since the generator isn't paused on a `yield` in the first call to `.next()`, anything passed into the first `.next()` is is just ignored.

If there are no `yield` statements left, whatever the function returns will be the last iterator value.

At this point the `done` flag will be set to `true` and any further calls to `.next()` will return the same value.

---

#### Running Example

So, in terms of your code, here's what is happening. I'll comment out each line that happens after an execution step.

**Step 1**

```
f = foo();
```

At this point, the iterator is created and stored in `f` but no code in the generator has actually ran. So we have:

```
function* () {
  console.log('generator 1');
  console.log('yield 1', yield 'A');
  console.log('generator 2');
  console.log('yield 2', yield 'B');
  console.log('generator 3');
};
```

**Step 2**

```
f.next('a'); // returns { value: 'A', done: false }
```

This runs the code within the generator up to the first `yield` and pushes the yielded `'A'` out of the `.next()` call. The `'a'` that is passed into `.next()` is just ignored, since its the first call (explained above).

Commenting out the lines that ran leaves us with:

```
function* () {
  // console.log('generator 1');
  console.log('yield 1', PAUSE_POINT); // we're paused on the `yield`. Essentially half of this line is done
  console.log('generator 2');
  console.log('yield 2', yield 'B');
  console.log('generator 3');
};
```

**Step 3**

```
f.next('b'); // return { value: 'B', done: false }
```

This returns `'b'` from the first `yield` (the first `PAUSE_POINT`) and runs the code to the next `yield`, pushing `'B'` out from the iterator.

Removing the lines that run leaves with:

```
function* () {
  // console.log('generator 1');
  // console.log('yield 1', 'b'); // this PAUSE_POINT returns 'b'
  // console.log('generator 2');
  console.log('yield 2', PAUSE_POINT); // no we're paused here
  console.log('generator 3');
};
```

**Step 4**

```
f.next('c'); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Which passes `'c'` out of the paused `yield` and, since there are no more `yields` left, runs to the end of the generator and pushes out whatever the generator returns, which in your case is just an implicit `return undefined`. Since we reached the end of the generator function, the `done` flag is set to `true`.

```
function* () {
  // console.log('generator 1');
  // console.log('yield 1', 'b'); // this PAUSE_POINT returns 'b'
  // console.log('generator 2');
  // console.log('yield 2', 'c'); // this PAUSE_POINT returns 'c'
  // console.log('generator 3');
  // here we have an implicit return undefined;
};
```

**Step 5 and further on**

```
f.next('d'); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Any calls to `.next()` after the generator is finished (i.e. `done` is `true`) just returns whatever the last value was. Passing `'d'` into this method serves no purpose anymore.

---

#### Additional Example

```js
var foo = function* () {
  console.log('first call to next runs to yield #1');
  var a = yield 'A'; // this yield pushes 'A' and returns 'a'
  console.log('second call to next runs to yield #2');
  var b = yield 'B'; // this yield pushes 'B' and returns 'b'
  console.log('third call to next runs to the end of the generator ');
  // there's no return statement here so we are returning undefined
};

var f = foo();

console.log(f.next('this gets ignored')); // { value: 'A', done: false }
console.log(f.next('a'));                 // { value: 'B', done: false }
console.log(f.next('b'));                 // { value: undefined, done: true }

// any further call just returns whatever the last returned value was
console.log(f.next('this also gets ignored since we are done')); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Comment: The things that is kind of weird with me, is why the line `console.log('yield 1', yield 'A');` is not executed fully, just the `yield 'A'` is executed to pass the 'A' to result object, the `'yield 1'` string is executed the next time

Comment: Because that's how a generator is defined. It is a pausable-function that gets paused on each `yield`, no matter if its in the middle of the line or on its own line. When you call `.next()`, you go the next `yield` and pause. Then if you call `next` again, you start from where you were paused and do the same again. Take a close look at **step3** of my answer, where `PAUSE_POINT` becomes `'b'`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your detail explanation. Great!

Comment: @Karim glad to help out :D

Answer (score 4):

Simple explain is that `yield` keyword stops executing code, `yield` is like breakpoint, next generator call executes code after last breakpoint to next breakpoint ( if any exists ). So generator function is called in parts, check comments in my example code.

```js
var gen=function*(){
  
  //1.start of first call next()
  
  yield "A";//1.here first next() ends
  
  //2.start of second call next();
  
  yield "B";//2.here end second next();
  
  //3.start of third call next()
  
  
  yield "C";//3.end of third next() call
  
  //NEXT AFTER THIRD. here every next() after third starts
  
  //no code no yield so value is undefined
  
  //here every next() after third ends
  
  
}();

console.log(gen.next().value);//A
console.log(gen.next().value);//B
console.log(gen.next().value);//C
console.log(gen.next().value);//undefined
```